# Problem with user hierarchy mapping for Sales Team management app - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I need your help/guidance  as 'm new to django-python web development and i'm stuck at one of my project. Below are the explained scenario for your reference.

Project : Sales team management webapp
platform : Django- python

This app has multiple users Ie. customer, dealer, sales manager, regional manager and admins. So i need to create account for all of them with respective privileges. 
All of the user should be mapped to each other Ie. customer

Upper user can see data of their mapped lower user.

**What i have done:

I have created models for all of the users and able to get them registered using views.

Where i'm stucK:

Unable to map the users to each other 
Also wants to show the upper hierarchy as selection dropdown while registration. which im unable to do.**

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth

roles = (
('DGM', 'DGM'),
('RM', 'RM'),
('ASM', 'ASM'),
('TSE', 'TSE'),
('Dealer', 'Dealer'),
('Painter', 'Painter')
)

class Depot(models.Model):
depot_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, auto_created=True, 
unique=True, verbose_name='ID')
depot_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
depot_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
depot_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class DGM(models.Model):
dgm_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
dgm_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
dgm_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
dgm_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
dgm_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
dgm_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dgm_pics', null=True, 
default='user_icon.png')
role = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='DGM')
dgm_depot = models.ManyToManyField(Depot)
dgm_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=states)
dgm_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class RM(models.Model):
username_rm = models.CharField(max_length=100)
rm_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
rm_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
rm_password = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
rm_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
rm_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
rm_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
rm_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='rm_pics', null=True, 
default='user_icon.png')
role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='RM')
rm_depot = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=depot)
rm_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=states)
rm_dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
rm_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
 on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ASM(models.Model):
username_asm = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
asm_password = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
asm_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
asm_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
asm_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
asm_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
asm_depot = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=depot)
asm_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=states)
role = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='ASM')
asm_dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
asm_rm = models.ForeignKey(RM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
asm_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TSE(models.Model):
username_tse = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
tse_password = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
tse_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
tse_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
tse_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
tse_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
tse_depot = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=depot)
tse_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=states)
tse_city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
tse_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tse_pics', null=True, 
default='user_icon.png')
role = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='TSE')
tse_dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
tse_rm = models.ForeignKey(RM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
tse_asm = models.ForeignKey(ASM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
tse_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Dealer(models.Model):
username_d = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
tse_password = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
dealer_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
dealer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
dealer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
dealer_shopname = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
dealer_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
dealer_depot = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=depot)
dealer_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=states)
dealer_city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
tse_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dealer_pics', null=True, 
default='user_icon.png')
role = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Dealer')
dealer_dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
dealer_rm = models.ForeignKey(RM, null=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
dealer_asm = models.ForeignKey(ASM, null=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
dealer_tse = models.ForeignKey(TSE, null=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
dealer_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Painter(models.Model):
username_p = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
password1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='painterpass')
password2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
p_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, verbose_name='ID')
p_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
p_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
p_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
p_address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
p_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
p_state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
p_depot = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
p_zone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
p_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='painter_pics', null=True, default='user_icon.png')
p_balance = models.FloatField(default=0)
role = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Painter')
p_dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
p_tse = models.ForeignKey(TSE, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
p_asm = models.ForeignKey(ASM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
p_rm = models.ForeignKey(RM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
p_dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
p_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
USERNAME_FIELD = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name='username', max_length=100)
```

Comment: could you add your model

Comment: I have added the models. please check . thanks